# Prove limit of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Assume  $\space a_0=1 $ and for each natural n, $a_n = sin(a_{n-1}) .$ prove:  $$ 
 \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n a_{n} ^2=\frac{1}{3}  
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. By Stolz-Cesaro's Theorem
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n a_{n} ^2&=&\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\frac1{a_{n}^2}}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac1{a_{n+1}^2}-\frac1{a_{n}^2}}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n}^2a_{n+1}^2}{a_{n}^2-a_{n+1}^2}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n^2\sin^2a_n}{a_n^2-\sin^2a_n}\\
&=&\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin^2x}{x^2-\sin^2x}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\frac{x^4}{x^2-\sin^2x}=3.
\end{eqnarray}